# How to manage 2D lists to iterate them and report out mixed values with last element of one list deleted

Tags: python, arrays, list

I need to do following:

```
list1 = [2,4,6,8]
list2 = [2,4,6,8]
```

I have already tried to do 2 for loops to iter each one of the lists
Then and try to delete the last element. Haven't worked already.

```
#I need to iter them and get combinations as follow:

[2,2]
[2,4]
[2,6]
[2,8] #this would be the largest element
[4,2]
[4,4]
[4,6] #then maximum minus one element
[6,2]
[6,4] #then maximum minus one element
[8,2] #until the first element is the last one
```

Comment: please provide some code from where we can take it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list2) - i):
        print(list1[i], “,”, list2[j])
```